# update user permissions of a google sheet using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet and i need to update the user permissions as below

1. Add abc@gmail.com to sheet and give editor access (working with below code )

```js
Drive.Permissions.insert(
   {
     'role': 'writer',
     'type': 'user',
     'value': 'abc@gmail.com'
   },
   sourceFileId,
   {
     'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
   });
```

2. For all the users emails  apart from abc@gmail.com,  I need to make them  just viewer access

Step -2 Im not able to achieve , please help me.Thanks

Comment: About `all the users emails apart from abc@gmail.com`, if you know all email addresses, you can add them as the viewers. If you don't know them, as a workaround, how about publicly sharing as the viewer? But if those were not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: all the user's emails I mean whoever is marked as editors for that particular sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: Hi Tanaike np at all , my ask is simple I'm looking for a script where I can convert editors to viewers